# Yii2 using relation get the login user information

Tags: php, yii2, relationship

I have work with Yii2,i want to get the login user DOB,email and some other filed(from customer table).

**Code in User Model**

```
/**
 * @property Customers $customer
 */

    public function getCustomer()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(Customers::className(), ['id' => 'customer_id']);
        }
```

then i used in my custom view file :

```
$_user->customer->email
```

but i am getting "Getting unknown property"

Comment: how are you passing $_user to view?

Comment: $user = User::findAll(); i have to list all the customer, so i collect all the customer from this query then pass to $this->render('view',array('user'=>$user))

Comment: try $user then. without _

Answer (score 1):

Is better if you add also a getter in model

```
 /* Getter for customer_email */
public function getCustomer_email() {
    return $this->customer->email;
}
```

then in your view you can easy refer to this data calling

```
$model->customer_email
```

on i a gridview using the attribute customer_email ...